# Getting error when I add constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a static `UITableView` with a `UICollectionView` and a `UILabel` that I added `constraints` programmatically to. Here is the code:

```
[_labelToChange setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_datesCollectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_labelToChange(30)]-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_labelToChange]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
2015-06-05 12:52:14.102 myApp[2373:44139] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1d80470 V:[DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa2e1d7f6d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1d80510 V:|-(0)-[DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa2e1d7f6d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9740 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fa2e1da8970]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9990 V:[UILabel:0x7fa2e1da8970]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9a10 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00(85)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9a60 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da4a50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa2e1d7f6d0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9990 V:[UILabel:0x7fa2e1da8970]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00]>
```

Comment: Why don't you add constraints by Xcode Interface Builder itself? Select UI elements and add constraints by that four tiny buttons in the bottom-right corner of IB. It is the best way

Comment: I would, but I'm making the 2 objects programmatically.

Comment: This looks like the same problem that I fixed for you in a previous question. You shouldn't have a height constraint on the collection view -- its height will be determined by the other constraints, and the height of the cell.

Comment: I don't actually see where you give the collection view a height in the code you posted, but this line in the error log, `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9a10 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00(85)]>`, is saying that you have a height of 85 for the collection view.

Comment: @rdelmar I took away the height constraint. Half the error from the other question is still here, (as shown above.) The project I sent in the previous question worked, but with the main project, when I inserted `[self.datesCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];`, and I take away the height constraint, I get the above error, and the collectionView doesn't scroll to position. But when I removed the label height constraint, and set the collectionView constraint, the collectionView scrolled almost to position. The selected cell was all the way to the left.

Comment: I don't know what to say. You need to figure out what's different between the project you sent me, and this one.

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry if I drove you crazy!! I was just so frustrated that it wasn't working. If you're interested, there is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698093/uicollectionview-is-not-scrolling-to-position#answer-30701034 Thanks for all the work and effort you put in!! :)