# UICollectionView is not scrolling to position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in a static `UITableView`. I'm trying to make the `collectionView` scroll to an `indexPath` in `viewDidLoad`. It's not scrolling to position on startup, when I select an `indexPath` it scrolls to that position. I made a clean project that produces the problem.

I thought the simplest way to do this was instead of making you to try and recreate the problem, I would just upload it. So here it is: [Project with problem](http://jmp.sh/rv8oj5k)

Comment: Posting code in a gist or something similar will more likely get you help. A lot of people won't be willing to download a random zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!! Where can I upload a whole project? Just checked up gist and I don't think I can upload the storyboard.

Comment: @Eric The best way would be to push it to Github

Comment: If you're trying to update UI, then viewDidLoad is not the method for you. But viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear.

Comment: @OmarAl-Shammary Tried that, but didn't solve the problem. But thanx. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: It was too difficult and time consuming to figure out how to upload a simple project to github. So I just unzipped the file and uploaded it to jumpShare. This way you can see what you're downloading. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two small problems:

1.The `selectedDate` does not match with your `dates` array. Compare the two date in the following image:
[image]

2.You should update UI in `viewDidAppear` as @Omar Al-Shammary said.

**The Solution:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self setSelectedDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]];
}
```

Comment: THANKS!! I've been working on this problem for days trying to solve it!! I can finally proceed on my project! Thanks!!